# Do you know VFP report library for developers?

Tags: pdf, report, reporting, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm looking for good report library for Visual FoxPro, but it seems that there is lot "old" solutions with bad documentation. Does anyone have experience with some VFP report library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend [www.eqeus.com](http://www.eqeus.com) for generating foxpro reports. They have also cloud report viewer and management.

Answer (score 1):

"old" solutions? Isn't it natural that a language whose last version was released on 2007 and even the latest hotfix release was in 2009 have solutions as "old"? What is old? 1,2, 10, or 20 years? Probably the VFP9's own reporting system, and the documentation written by Cathy Pountney is considered good by many including me. 
There are other reporting solutions some of which are free and some of which are not. For example you might check out [Report Sculptor (free)](http://www.report-sculptor.com) from my friend Djordjevic Srdjan. Or you might check out another from one of my other friend Rich Simpson [Mind's Eye reporting engine (paid)](http://www.mindseyeinc.com). I have been using Mind's eye for years and I found its documentation well. Report Sculptor too is documented enough IMHO.

Old/new, good/bad are relative terms and be different from person to person. With your measures, either you didn't see the default reporting tool and Cathy's doucmentation, and those two engines yet or your 'good' expectation is much above mine.

Answer (score 1):

In our company we are using [Eqeus report library.](http://www.eqeus.com/) We had really great experience with them. They have good [documentation](https://eqeuscom.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DOC/Developer%27s+guide) and their customer support always helped us. I think that free solutions cannot beat commercial use for this purpose.